# Google Sheets Query Ordering not working

Tags: google-sheets-query

I have a function in Google Sheets to Query my data, and it works perfectly fine, until I try to order it.

The function is...

```
=query('Master Accounts List'!A1:I,"select A,B,C,E,F where E='"&A3&"' OR C="&A2)
```

As soon as I attempt to add `order by A desc` it gives me a **Formula Parse Error**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=query('Master Accounts List'!A1:I,"select A,B,C,E,F where E='"&A3&"' OR C='&A2&' order by A desc")
```